# LLDB: Disassemble functions at pointer location (Obj-C/macOS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, reverse-engineering, lldb, objective-c-runtime

When trying to debug applications written in Objective-C I often see that the registers contain a pointer to a function.  The problem is, I cannot seem to get to the actual implementation.

Example:

```
$register read
$rbx = 0x00007fffd1b326b8  (void *)0x001dffffd1b32731
$x/2xw $rbx
$0x7fffd1b326b8: 0xd1b32731 0x001dffff (flipped endian)
$x/2xw 0x001dffffd1b32731
$error: memory read failed for 0x1dffffd1b32600
```

Obviously, I cannot set a breakpoint at that address either so that eliminates that option so my question is: is it possible to get to the instructions that are supposedly at that memory address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the address of a function, you can see the assembly of that function using `disassemble -a` command.

```
(lldb) disassemble -a 0x1234
```

or

```
(lldb) disas -a 0x1234
```